# Apache to execute a script if it is unable to connect to fcgi server

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

How would one setup Apache to execute a script if it is unable to connect to fcgi server/socket?
Once the script is run, it would try to start the fcgi server/socket and retry/continue the whole request.

I know that "mod_actions" could potentialy do that, but they execute scripts/actions on every request - I only need to do it once fcgi is down.

An example command line of how I made Apache to use fcgi:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080 *:4433>
    ...
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Why do I need this? I want to open multiple php-fpm instances on request and close them after 60 seconds of no usage.

**Maybe there is a different approach for the same result?**

Comment: Probably a script in LUA would do that and HTTPD supports lua officially through mod_lua.

Comment: Has a lot of options, but I can't see any hooks for timeouts, errors, proxy related callbacks. Any other suggestions, or am I missing something?